# form validation javascript stop new window from opening

Tags: javascript, forms, new-window

I have written a large page including a form as my first JavaScript project. I've gotten some help here, so thanks. I am very happy with what I have so far, but I have one last problem I need to deal with.

The code I will submit here is a tester. I have a couple of functions attached to an onClick new window. What happens is user submits form and their info appears in a new window. (My original page is more complicated, of course.) There is one function called askForHelp which shows an alert in the new window if a specific value is entered for 'state' and a very simple validateForm which shows an alert on the parent?? window if values are left blank.

The problem is b/c i have all the functions running onClick, and I realize they run concurrently, the new window opens no matter what the user does (with the alerts showing in their various places).

Based on other similar questions here, I tried adding a return false and return true statements to my conditionals, but this hasn't done anything.

Now I know there are much better ways to do what I am doing here, and that my form validation is basic and weak, but as my first foray into programming, it was very important for me to understand everything I am doing, which I do, as of now.

Can anyone show me how to fix this so the new window only opens if the form validates? I would prefer no jquery or no radical chances to the code, if possible.

I appreciate everyone's input. Here is the code:

```
   <!doctype html>
      <html>
         <head>
           <title>test</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

       <script type="text/javascript">

          function newWindow() {
            allInfo= open("", "displayWindow");

              allInfo.document.open();

          allInfo.document.write('<!doctype html><html><head><title>Test</title><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>');
          allInfo.document.write(document.getElementById ('state').value);
          allInfo.document.write('<p>' + document.getElementById ('zip').value);
          allInfo.document.write('</section></body></html>');

              allInfo.document.close();
             }

           function askForHelp () {

              var volunteer = document.getElementById('state').value;

                if ((volunteer == "New York") || (volunteer == "NY") || (volunteer == "New Jersey") || (volunteer == "NJ")) { 
                  allInfo.alert("test test test");
                     return false;
             }
                else {
                     return true; 
             }
             }

            function validateForm () {
              var x = document.getElementById("state").value;
              var y = document.getElementById("zip").value;
                if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "") {
                  alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
                     return false;
             }
                else {
                     return true;
             } 
             }


       </script>

      </head>

          <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       </script>

           <form id="infoForm" method="post" name="infoForm">
              <p>State: </p>
                 <p><input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State or Region"></p>

              <p>Zip: </p>
                 <p><input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="Zip code" required /></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Submit Information" onClick="newWindow(), askForHelp(), validateForm()" ></p>
           </form>
          </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code? It is very difficult to read like this.

Comment: I tried to format it better. Got an answer below that works perfectly for what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing an onClick with `newWindow(), askForHelp(), validateForm()`
Why not just do one of them (which you want to check first) and then have the function call the others when ready?

```
 function validateForm () {
   var x = document.getElementById("state").value;
   var y = document.getElementById("zip").value;
   if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "") {
     alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
     return false;
   } else {
     newWindow(); //Validation was successful so lets open the new window
   }
 }
```

This way you can have only `validateForm()` trigger on click, and the rest will trigger when they need to. You'll need to add `askForHelp()` inside of the newWindow function to have that trigger when necessary as well.

Comment: ok I'll try that, but don't I still need to have the function execute when the user submits the form?

Comment: Yeah, it will execute when they submit the form, but only after validation passes. validateForm will execute first and then execute newWindow

Comment: Awesome! This makes it work exactly how I want it to, at least on this test code -- but it should work with the real page too. I put onClick=validateForm() and I put newWindow() as the ese conditional in the validateForm function (as you put above) -- then I added askForHelp to the bottom of the newWindow function. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a shameless plug, but I just wrote an open source JS library that attempts to solve problems like this. I call it "Is".

http://jumpkick-studios.github.io/Is/

It uses the Maybe Monad concept:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/Maybe

So it would let you solve this problem with more of a Single Responsibility Principle.

```
var validateState=function(obj){
  return (obj.state!=null) //error check here
}
var validateZip=function(obj){
  return (obj.zip!=null) //error check here 
}
var openWindow=function(){
  //do open window stuff
}

var handleError(){
  //handle errors here
}

var onClick=function(e){
  var form={state:document.getElementById("state").value, zip:document.getElementById("zip").value})
  new jumpkick.Is(form)
    .is(validateState)
    .is(validateZip)
    .then(openWindow)
    .catch(handleError)
    .finally(function(){
      //anything else can go here
    });
}
```

ETA: Perhaps an even better way to approach this is to not have a single handle error function, since you may want to display messaging for each wrong field.

So maybe even something like this would work (a little more code though).

```
var onClick=function(e){
      var validInput=true;
      var state=document.getElementById("state").value, zip=document.getElementById("zip").value
      new jumpkick.Is(state)
        .not().isLongerThan(0)        
        .then(function(){
            validInput=false;
            //display message for state
         });
       new jumpkick.Is(zip)
        .not().isLongerThan(0)        
        .then(function(){
            validInput=false;
            //display message for zip
         });
    if(validInput) // openWindow
    }
```

Comment: Neat but not really what the question was about at all.

Comment: How so? I seriously didn't mean to spam, but it seems like the question is about how to organize the code so a series of validations take place prior to opening a window. Certain code should trigger no matter what, and the end result should happen only after all validation takes place. Wouldn't this be a good use a mondadic chain? Also, shouldn't breaking out his code into SRP functions help solve the problem as well?

Comment: I read the question as specifically limited to "why do I always get a popup and how do I prevent it". While to your answer's credit, it  **does** partially address this. It does so however by introducing a dependency and heavily restructuring (something the OP specifically indicated they didn't want) to a relatively advanced programming concept (when they specifically said they want to fully understand the code). I agree the OP's code can be a lot better and your library is neat, but that is best left for the [codereview stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Fair enough! In my mind, breaking things out into smaller functions makes it easier for me to understand, which is why I tried to illustrate that in my answer. But thanks for the feedback.